# Postgres: prevent new user from creating tables, without superuser

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

In Cloud SQL Postgres, where superuser permissions are not accessible, how can I prevent a new user from creating tables?

I know that `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public` works, but this seem to require superuser permissions, as I get a `WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"` error.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run that statement as the user who owns `public`.

Comment: I see. The owner in the case is the superuser `cloudsqladmin`, which can't be accessed. Any way around that?

Comment: Unless Google hacked up PostgreSQL's security system, no. If they provide an unsafe default like that without giving you a way to change it, choose another service provider.